# bash parameter expansion and combining pattern-matching operators

Tags: bash, parameter-expansion

Is it possible to use parameter expansion to combine pattern-matching operators?

For example, given the variable `test=/home/archie/.vimrc.bak`.

I can delete the longest match from the beginning of `$test` with `echo ${test##*/}`:

```
>> echo ${test##*/}
.vimrc.bak
```

I can also delete the shortest match from the end of `$test` with `echo ${test%.*}`:

```
>> echo ${test%.*}
/home/archie/.vimrc
```

Is there a way to combine the two pattern-matching operators to output `.vimrc`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do it in a single expansion, but you can do it with two:

```
$ test=/home/archie/.vimrc.bak; tmp="${test%.*}"; name="${tmp##*/}"; echo "$name"
.vimrc
```